# Responsive Background Image - Fullscreen

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am making a simple landing page and am trying to get the following image to be the background fullscreen: [image](https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431538510849-b719825bf08b?q=80&fm=jpg&s=6fd7a983e3b43e66d2b6062856b9df66)

My CSS currently looks like this:

```
body {
    background-image: url('/images/bg.jpeg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

A majority of the image is getting cut off, what's the best way to remedy this?

Thanks !

Comment: `background-size: cover`? Also note there will never be an ideal ratio for your images on all different devices (e.g. screen dimensions). Hence you might lose some of the image in a lot of cases. The trick is to centralise the image' content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you tried this :

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background: url('/images/bg.jpeg') no-repeat center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a cool idea for a landing page. The background, being fixed is a popular cool way for landing pages. Please, to see this properly, click "Full Page" on the top right after clicking run code snippet.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300);

div:nth-child(1){
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431538510849-b719825bf08b?q=80&fm=jpg&s=6fd7a983e3b43e66d2b6062856b9df66);
  height: 750px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  
}

div:nth-child(2){
  height:400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 300px;
  z-index: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
  font-size: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1> Michael Barreiro </h1>
</div>

<div></div>
```